# Not recieving message from SimpMessagingTemplate

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

I'm trying to send a message intended for a specific user by having the client subscribe to a topic and then have the server send a message to that destination.

On the client side, the user will subscribe to: `/user/{userId}/queue/friend-requests`, in this case `/user/7/queue/friend-requests`.

On the server side, I would first when the websocket connection is established set the principal name to the `{userId}`. So after the connection when I print inside the server `userRegistry.getUsers()` I get this printed `[name=[7], sessions={e0a8db6b-90e9-c464-5409-c1ac71560e8d=id=e0a8db6b-90e9-c464-5409-c1ac71560e8d, subscriptions={0=destination=/user/7/queue/friend-requests, 1=destination=/topic}}]` where `name = [7]` would be the users unique userID.

On the server side, when I send a message to `"/app/friend-requests"` it get sucessfully recieved by this controller class:

```
@Controller
public class FriendRequestController {
    private SessionToken sessionToken;
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;
    @Autowired
    private FriendRequestService friendRequestService;

@MessageMapping("/friend-requests")
public void sendFriendRequest(@Payload FriendRequest friendRequest, Principal principal) throws InvalidSessionTokenException{

    System.out.println(userRegistry.getUsers());
    System.out.println(principal.getName());

    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - -");

    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("7", "/queue/friend-requests", "user specific");
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic", "topic");

    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - -");
```

However when I use `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(7, "/queue/friend-requests", "user specifiq");` to send the message to the user which would subscribe to `/user/7/queue/friend-requests` nothing happens. the client doesnt recieve the message and nothing gets printed inside the server either.

This is the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com/swoosh/springbootchatapp/chatapp/friend/system/stomp/friendrequest/controller"})
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer



{

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
    registry.addEndpoint("/friend-requests").setAllowedOrigins("*").setHandshakeHandler(new StompHandshakeHandler());
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic", "/user");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");

}
```

And this is the subcribtion on the client side:

```
        String destination = "/user/" + Main.getApplicationState().getUserId() + "/queue/friend-requests";
    stompFriendRequestsHandler.getSession().subscribe(destination, new StompFrameHandler() {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            // Return the expected payload type of the message
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.println("recived the user specifiq");
            System.out.println(payload);
        }
    });

    stompFriendRequestsHandler.getSession().subscribe("/topic", new StompFrameHandler() {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
            System.out.println("recieved the topic");
            System.out.println(payload);
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone know why. And also, when using `convertAndSendToUser`, will the first argument be used to find the `name` value for the specific websocket session?

Comment: I just now got this error "Could not find session id in GenericMessage [payload=user specifiq, headers={simpMessageType=MESSAGE, simpDestination=/user/[7]/queue/friend-requests}]" if that is to any help

Answer (score 0):

The server should send like this:

```java
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/friend-requests", "user specific");
```

and the client should subscribe `/user/queue/friend-requests`.